# What is the difference between registers with a $ sign and withought in risc V?

Tags: assembly, riscv

In my quizzes for risc V the questions will often vary between instructions being set in two different fromats. Either the instructions are like :

this:
`addi $t0,$t1,4`

or this:
`addi t0,t1,4`

My best guess is that the $ refers to the content in the register much like a pointer would work in c but this was never explained to us in class. Can anyone clarify the difference in notation and what the commands would execute ?

Comment: There is no difference. It depends on your assembler which syntax it expects. It definitely does not do pointer indirection, that is done by `($t0)` and using the appropriate load/store instruction.

Comment: The `$` is not used by RISC V for registers at all, to the best of my knowledge.  It is required for registeris in MIPS, and much coursework is transitioning from older, proprietary MIPS to newer, open-source RISC V.  So, not unusual to find MIPS era artifacts in RISC V coursework. In general, the two architectures are very similar.

Comment: RISC-V strictly follow RISC philosophy in its design. It can't use a memory source or destination for an `add` instruction.  Being a load/store ISA is one of the defining characteristics of a RISC, even ARM and AArch64 load+add in the same instruction, and they're the least RISCy of mainstream RISCs.

Comment: Have you tried assembling it yourself?  `clang -target riscv32 foo.s` says "unknown operand" on the `$` register names.  I haven't tried a simulator like RARS with its own built-in assembler.  If it accepts either version, you can check the machine code to verify that they assembled to the same instruction.